# How to delete a personal address book contact using ews-javascript-api

Tags: javascript, exchangewebservices, ews-javascript-api

I'm using the `ews-javascript-api` to delete a contact from my exchange personal address book.  I'm following the microsoft c# example (but obviously writing my code in javascript.  Here's the example I'm following:

[EWS Delete contact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee693008(v=exchg.80).aspx)

And here is my code to delete a contact.

```
    const itemId = new ews.ItemId(id);

    const contact = ews.Contact.Bind(window.exchangeService, itemId).then((response) => {
        if (response) {
            response.Delete(ews.DeleteMode.MoveToDeletedItems).then(response => {
                dispatch( addressBookAction.deleteContactSuccess(response));

                // Refresh our PAB
                dispatch( addressBookAction.fetchAddressbook());
            }).catch((error) => {
                dispatch( addressBookAction.deleteContactFailure(error));
            });;
        }
    });
```

Where id is a real id of a contact.  I'm getting it by calling `contact.Id.UniqueId`

I'm getting an error when I try the `ews.Contact.Bind` and passing it the ItemId object created from my contact id.  It says the id is not formed correctly.

Ideas?

Comment: The error means the Id your passing in isn't correct or being changed by another process. Eg the Id should be a Base64 value, you don't show the code where you getting that value which is probably where the error is

Comment: instead of creating new ItemId, what happens if you use `contact.Id` when using bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of creating `new ItemId()`, use `contact.Id` when using bind.

Answer (score 0):

Gautam was correct.  I was taking the Id.UniqueId and using that to create a new ItemId object to use for the delete.  If I just pass contact.Id it works.  ty